# PublicKey handling Java / PHP

Tags: java, php, openssl, rsa

I'm currently stuck with the problem of RSA key management. To be specific, I want to create an RSA keypair in Java, sign some content (i.e. a String) export the public key, the signature, and the signed String into a JSON file (yes, a JSON!), import it on another server using PHP, and validate the signature, meaning that I have to re-create a usable key from the JSON data.

Plus, I have to do it the other way around (create in PHP, verify in Java)

Plus, I need to export the private keys into JSON (Yes, JSON again :) !) and export this.

So on the Java side, everything seems to work smoothly. I can create keys, export them to JSON, re-import them, and use them. Creating and verifying signatures is no problem. Here is the code:

creating a keypair:

```
public static final String  ALGORITHM           = "RSA";
public static final int     KEYSIZE             = 4096;
public static KeyPair createKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(KEYSIZE);

    return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
}
```

exporting the keys to a String (that will end up in the JSON Object) - the code for the private Key is similar:

```
public static final String  PUBLICKEY_PREFIX    = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
public static final String  PUBLICKEY_POSTFIX   = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
public static String exportPublicKey(Key key) {
    return PUBLICKEY_PREFIX + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(key.getEncoded()) + PUBLICKEY_POSTFIX;
}
```

The result of the above would be for example

```
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

then, I read the keys from the JSON again:

```
public static PublicKey importPublicKey(String key) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
    key = stripKey(key);
    byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
    return KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));
}

public static PrivateKey importPrivateKey(String key) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
    key = stripKey(key);
    byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
    return KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));
}
```

This works fine for me. I can create, store, re-import, and use the keys - both public and private. Signatures i create using

```
public static String createSignature(PrivateKey privateKey, String message) {
    String algorithm = "SHA512withRSA";
    Signature signature = null;
    String signedString = null;

    try {
        signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(message.getBytes());

        byte[] signatureByteArray = signature.sign();

        signedString = "-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----"
                + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(signatureByteArray)
                + "-----END SIGNATURE-----";
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signedString;    
}
```

can be verified easily using `java.security.Signature.verify()`. So far I'm happy.

Now the tricky part: I send the created JSONs to the other server, and here, my trouble starts:

First, I strip the header and trailer from the string ("-----BEGIN" and so on...), then, I use `base64_decode()`, and ASSUME, that the result would be usable as a key with a call of `openssl_pkey_get_private()`

Anyhow, I get errors like

```
openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key
```

every time I try to use my keys.

So In Java, I create a `new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)`, yet, in PHP, there is no such functionality (?)

Where does my en/decoding go wrong? I'm actually a bit lost :(

Comment: add one example of file/message generated (Base64), and key pairs. for test some code and give you some code to do that

Comment: So you're packing the *public* key along with the message, and then on the receiving end in PHP you call openssl_pkey_get_*private*(), and it's not working? Hmmm.... maybe you should show your code.

Comment: No not exactly :D I pass the message with the public key (assuming, that the key fingerprint has been exchanged prior to that) and then i want to get the PUBLIC key to do the trick. Anyhow - the same exporting/formatting should be done with the private keys in order to get them from one system to another. then - and only then - obviously, I#d get the private key from the encoded private key string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like I found my answer. Here goes some example code that turned out to work just fine:

```
public class KeyTest{
static final String ALGORITHM           = "RSA";
static final int    KEYSIZE             = 1024;

static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA512withRSA";

static final String PUBLICKEY_PREFIX    = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
static final String PUBLICKEY_POSTFIX   = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
static final String PRIVATEKEY_PREFIX   = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
static final String PRIVATEKEY_POSTFIX  = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(KEYSIZE);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

        // THIS IS java.security

        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

        System.out.println("Public java.security: Algorithm: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm() + "Format: " + publicKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("Private java.security: Algorithm: " + privateKey.getAlgorithm() + "Format: " + privateKey.getFormat() + "\n");

        // THIS IS DER:

        byte[] publicKeyDER = publicKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKeyDER = privateKey.getEncoded();

        System.out.println("Public DER: "+Arrays.toString(publicKeyDER));
        System.out.println("Private DER: "+Arrays.toString(privateKeyDER) + "\n");

        // THIS IS PEM:

        String publicKeyPEM = PUBLICKEY_PREFIX + "\n" + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(publicKey.getEncoded()).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n") + "\n" + PUBLICKEY_POSTFIX;
        String privateKeyPEM = PRIVATEKEY_PREFIX + "\n" + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(privateKey.getEncoded()).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n") + "\n" + PRIVATEKEY_POSTFIX;

        System.out.println("Public PEM: " + "\n"+publicKeyPEM);
        System.out.println("Private PEM: " + "\n"+privateKeyPEM + "\n");

        // Signing the teststring
        String message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(message.getBytes());

        byte[] signatureByteArray = sig.sign();

        String signature = "-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----" + "\n"
                    + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(signatureByteArray).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n") + "\n"
                    + "-----END SIGNATURE-----";

        System.out.println("Message Plaintext: " + message);
        System.out.println("Signature: " + "\n" + signature + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The output of this is something like this:

```
Public java.security: Algorithm: RSAFormat: X.509
Private java.security: Algorithm: RSAFormat: PKCS#8

Public DER: [48, -127, -97, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, -127, -115, 0, 48, -127, -119, 2, -127, -127, 0, -125, -8, 66, -86, -27, -55, 14, 50, 26, -103, -87, 102, 47, 126, -70, 57, -27, 103, -95, 10, 26, 25, -3, -18, -44, -85, 11, -19, -92, 111, 22, -6, 94, 79, -126, 32, -68, -82, -67, 24, -108, 9, 46, -100, 25, -37, 56, 2, -122, -31, -93, 56, -39, 79, -67, 33, -126, -13, -72, -120, 115, 3, -57, -120, -86, 119, 57, -110, -6, -11, -36, 109, -113, -69, -11, -81, -94, 47, 59, -7, 119, 108, -89, -26, -55, 117, -74, 125, -39, -1, 116, -116, -9, -60, -57, -78, -118, 45, 38, 120, -43, 123, -51, -104, 42, -47, 101, -120, 78, 9, -2, -84, 113, -42, -71, 101, 3, -44, -58, 39, 50, 96, 83, 90, 71, 41, 83, -13, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
Private DER: [48, -126, 2, 118, 2, 1, 0, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 4, -126, 2, 96, 48, -126, 2, 92, 2, 1, 0, 2, -127, -127, 0, -125, -8, 66, -86, -27, -55, 14, 50, 26, -103, -87, 102, 47, 126, -70, 57, -27, 103, -95, 10, 26, 25, -3, -18, -44, -85, 11, -19, -92, 111, 22, -6, 94, 79, -126, 32, -68, -82, -67, 24, -108, 9, 46, -100, 25, -37, 56, 2, -122, -31, -93, 56, -39, 79, -67, 33, -126, -13, -72, -120, 115, 3, -57, -120, -86, 119, 57, -110, -6, -11, -36, 109, -113, -69, -11, -81, -94, 47, 59, -7, 119, 108, -89, -26, -55, 117, -74, 125, -39, -1, 116, -116, -9, -60, -57, -78, -118, 45, 38, 120, -43, 123, -51, -104, 42, -47, 101, -120, 78, 9, -2, -84, 113, -42, -71, 101, 3, -44, -58, 39, 50, 96, 83, 90, 71, 41, 83, -13, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, -127, -128, 39, -40, 45, -16, -63, 62, 9, -18, 48, -65, -46, 56, -117, 0, 125, 35, 123, -46, -28, -7, 82, -42, 36, 40, 22, -57, -87, -21, 79, 41, 71, 75, -62, 107, -55, 3, 47, 84, -90, -67, 35, -4, -3, -72, -99, -55, -27, 72, 70, 7, 28, 43, -50, -40, -41, 102, -91, -50, 6, 26, 20, 119, -64, -89, 96, 97, -101, 103, -46, 34, 95, -91, 19, 43, 4, 63, -121, 30, 85, 11, 86, 33, 58, -62, -108, 74, 56, 81, -123, 24, -8, 121, -11, -119, 43, -97, -50, 24, -60, 72, -15, 6, -87, 123, -16, 123, -17, -39, 56, -44, 97, -57, -8, 16, 9, -72, 68, 53, 1, 87, 94, -16, -54, 115, 15, -34, 93, -23, 2, 65, 0, -59, 121, -7, -34, 118, -24, 27, -9, 83, -125, -115, 120, -78, 33, -122, -78, 7, 33, 18, -44, -57, -87, 50, 99, -105, -68, -69, -82, 116, 53, -119, 113, 41, -115, 83, 66, -55, -9, -47, -12, 49, -58, 14, 68, -76, 106, 95, 102, -96, 90, -61, -40, -17, -10, 81, 116, -6, -125, -68, -33, -18, -19, 43, -11, 2, 65, 0, -85, 20, 118, 69, 108, -51, 79, -63, 70, -35, -16, -47, 81, -48, 51, 36, 99, 79, -78, -84, -86, 41, 49, -56, 101, 100, -80, 121, 53, -5, -98, -9, 53, 110, 58, -60, -39, 39, 100, -64, -108, 36, -29, -127, -13, -110, 120, 46, -31, -79, -10, -36, -26, -94, -117, -6, -76, 121, -15, -17, -31, 94, -73, 71, 2, 64, 119, 0, 35, 48, 9, 77, -92, 20, -83, -47, -9, -67, -60, -14, 105, 29, -3, 39, -44, 22, 63, 95, 89, -117, 36, -108, 74, 49, 61, -68, 73, 95, -43, 31, 98, 14, 60, 113, 71, -89, 53, 27, 89, -37, -45, 48, -54, -34, -88, 65, 42, 6, 31, -52, -70, -105, -104, -93, 44, 125, 113, -104, -96, -59, 2, 64, 122, -26, 48, 48, -97, -128, -66, -110, -78, 62, 46, 9, -79, 36, 72, 25, 19, -34, -27, 20, 117, 9, 50, -30, 43, 52, -78, 49, -31, 61, -23, 108, -35, -51, 90, 26, -97, -123, 85, 51, -93, 56, -4, -41, 22, 11, 90, -101, 19, 55, -83, -121, -13, -121, 65, -41, -48, 94, -22, 22, -47, 104, 33, 113, 2, 65, 0, -65, 101, -127, -118, 21, 122, -114, 47, 65, -96, -37, -104, 100, 52, 38, -81, 9, -9, 120, -56, -36, -92, -52, 7, -47, -8, -101, 83, -24, -82, -81, -60, 71, -47, 111, -49, 1, 46, 16, -52, -87, -79, 21, -68, 22, 18, -37, -62, 33, 102, 40, -49, -122, -98, -83, 1, 94, 29, -85, 93, -16, -7, -57, 119]

Public PEM: 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCD+EKq5ckOMhqZqWYvfro55Weh
ChoZ/e7UqwvtpG8W+l5PgiC8rr0YlAkunBnbOAKG4aM42U+9IYLzuIhzA8eIqnc5
kvr13G2Pu/Wvoi87+Xdsp+bJdbZ92f90jPfEx7KKLSZ41XvNmCrRZYhOCf6scda5
ZQPUxicyYFNaRylT8wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
Private PEM: 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Message Plaintext: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Signature: 
-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
UxhWlr8Ks3PkfaKK8IGGolUs8qjvbE4dXs8ANUtJdw48g8nk6pOEuEscpSiszc1O
fBFEG6lexRFeW4+zpyWHN8oJpVaxz7sd2lstFqu/dUkU8HtPujKkwK6c/3pzsAt8
yHru/BPRwI8Wryqm2dfiHO4cXKq5rIXfj0sSXbwI1PE=
-----END SIGNATURE-----
```

Now I hardcoded these values in PHP:

```
<?php

$publicKeyPEM = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCD+EKq5ckOMhqZqWYvfro55Weh
ChoZ/e7UqwvtpG8W+l5PgiC8rr0YlAkunBnbOAKG4aM42U+9IYLzuIhzA8eIqnc5
kvr13G2Pu/Wvoi87+Xdsp+bJdbZ92f90jPfEx7KKLSZ41XvNmCrRZYhOCf6scda5
ZQPUxicyYFNaRylT8wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$privateKeyPEM = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAIP4QqrlyQ4yGpmp
Zi9+ujnlZ6EKGhn97tSrC+2kbxb6Xk+CILyuvRiUCS6cGds4AobhozjZT70hgvO4
iHMDx4iqdzmS+vXcbY+79a+iLzv5d2yn5sl1tn3Z/3SM98THsootJnjVe82YKtFl
iE4J/qxx1rllA9TGJzJgU1pHKVPzAgMBAAECgYAn2C3wwT4J7jC/0jiLAH0je9Lk
+VLWJCgWx6nrTylHS8JryQMvVKa9I/z9uJ3J5UhGBxwrztjXZqXOBhoUd8CnYGGb
Z9IiX6UTKwQ/hx5VC1YhOsKUSjhRhRj4efWJK5/OGMRI8Qape/B779k41GHH+BAJ
uEQ1AVde8MpzD95d6QJBAMV5+d526Bv3U4ONeLIhhrIHIRLUx6kyY5e8u650NYlx
KY1TQsn30fQxxg5EtGpfZqBaw9jv9lF0+oO83+7tK/UCQQCrFHZFbM1PwUbd8NFR
0DMkY0+yrKopMchlZLB5Nfue9zVuOsTZJ2TAlCTjgfOSeC7hsfbc5qKL+rR58e/h
XrdHAkB3ACMwCU2kFK3R973E8mkd/SfUFj9fWYsklEoxPbxJX9UfYg48cUenNRtZ
29Mwyt6oQSoGH8y6l5ijLH1xmKDFAkB65jAwn4C+krI+LgmxJEgZE97lFHUJMuIr
NLIx4T3pbN3NWhqfhVUzozj81xYLWpsTN62H84dB19Be6hbRaCFxAkEAv2WBihV6
ji9BoNuYZDQmrwn3eMjcpMwH0fibU+iur8RH0W/PAS4QzKmxFbwWEtvCIWYoz4ae
rQFeHatd8PnHdw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

$message_plaintext = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

$signature = "-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
UxhWlr8Ks3PkfaKK8IGGolUs8qjvbE4dXs8ANUtJdw48g8nk6pOEuEscpSiszc1O
fBFEG6lexRFeW4+zpyWHN8oJpVaxz7sd2lstFqu/dUkU8HtPujKkwK6c/3pzsAt8
yHru/BPRwI8Wryqm2dfiHO4cXKq5rIXfj0sSXbwI1PE=
-----END SIGNATURE-----";

function verify_signature($message, $public_key, $signature) {
    $algorithm = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA512;
    $hash_algorithm = 'sha512';

    $signature = str_replace('-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----', '', $signature);
    $signature = str_replace('-----END SIGNATURE-----', '', $signature);
    $signature = base64_decode($signature);
    $success = openssl_verify($message, $signature, $public_key,    $algorithm);
    return $success;
}

var_dump(verify_signature($message_plaintext, $publicKeyPEM, $signature));

?>
```

...and this actually works. I still don't see why Jack's solution didn't work, but oh well...

Hope this helps other folks to manage keys, since I didn't find much cross-platform examples on the net...

One site I'd recommend though is http://pumka.net/2009/12/19/reading-writing-and-converting-rsa-keys-in-pem-der-publickeyblob-and-privatekeyblob-formats/

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

Your key is currently stored in binary format, which is usually known as "DER" format. That is the way Java stores the key. To be able to read it from PHP, you have to convert the key to PEM format, which is the format for OpenSSL. As a result, PHP requires that the key be in PEM format. Here is a PHP function which can convert DER encoded keys to PEM encoded keys in PHP:

```
function X509_to_pem($der_data) {

    $BEGIN= "-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----";
    $END = "-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----";

    $base64Encoded= base64_encode($der_data);

    $pem = $BEGIN . "\n";
    $pem .= chunk_split($base64Encoded, 64, "\n");
    $pem .= $END . "\n";

    return $pem;
}
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that the missing linebreaks cause the error on PHP side? I'm at home now - I will test this tomorrow and post the results.